# Angular unit test http call - test is splicing up the query param into query params

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Using Angular 12, I have this service which has this call

```
    consumeGetPatientsToReconcile(query) {
      const host = this.appConfigService.apiBaseUrl;
      const url = `${host}/foo/bar`;
                          
      const obs = this.http.get(          
        url,
        { params: query }
      );
      return obs.pipe(tap((data) => this.reconcileMainService.setReconcileData(data) ));
    }
```

and I have this unit test

```
    it('should consume patients reconcile api', () => {
      service.consumeGetPatientsToReconcile('page=1').subscribe((data) => {});
      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('host/foo/bar');
      const foo = req.request.params.get('page')
      console.log(foo);
  
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });
```

but in the test it is splicing up the query params `page`

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: host/foo/bar", found none. Requests received are: GET host/foo/bar?0=p&1=a&2=g&3=e&4==&5=1.

Also, it seems the param is missing in `req.request.params.get('page')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass directly a string as `params` property of `options` argument for `HttpClient.get` (or request in general).
It expects an object of type `HttpParams`, so you need to create one.
Your case is quite trivial so you can simply do

```
const obs = this.http.get(          
  url,
  { params: new HttpParams().set('page', '1') }
);
```

while for more complex situation, you can leverage `HttpParamsOptions` utilities like `fromObject`.

In general, I suggest to better type your code, and maybe rethink your project's structure, because that method returning a `tap`ped observable is quite unusual and doesn't smell too nicely.

Comment: These routes are consumed by the router with data guards...used to have data on first paint ready. Maybe that is why it looks unusual?

Comment: There's no route involved in the code you posted. Anyway, the last part of my message is not strictly related to your problem.
The solution should be the one I gave you there.